# What is this orb?

Tags: astroneer

[image: Orb]

So I found this while trying to get to the center of the starting planet, I also tried researching it but it just says 'This item is not reasearchable'

[image: Trying to research the orb]

Is it just a dev thing that the dev's left? or is it just for decoration?

Really unsure what this is and I would just like to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've found a [Zebra Ball](https://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Marbles), and you're on the right track thinking it's a dev leftover:

> According to developers, the objects were originally used for testing physics and light systems, but were accidentally left in the game.

These marbles didn't have much use at all until recently with the addition of the [Recreation Canopy](https://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Recreational_Canopy), which lets you play a bit of footie with the ball.